# Geolocation with openlayers limits

Tags: geolocation, openlayers

Are there any limitations to the geolocation with openlayers? (number of requests, unreliability etc?)

Thank you, 
Alex

Comment: Do you refer to the ol.Geolocation class? That's a HTML5 helper class. The reliability is dependent on the browser support.

Comment: i'm refering to geolocation.getPosition(). Like in this example: [http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/geolocation.htm](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/geolocation.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought so. No restrictions on that with OpenLayers. As in my comment. The browser gets the location from the HTML5 class.

Comment: OK. Thank you. So the only restriction would be for the browser to support HTML5. D you have any experience with that? I've read about some issues with ie11.

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem on a mobile device. You will be asked by the application whether you allow to share your geolocation. I have IE only on a desktop PC where the IP will be used to get an approximate location.